# Folding with trees

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tree, higher-order-functions

I was trying to implement a `foldTree` function to generate a balanced binary tree from a list of values using `foldr` (Question 2 [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/04-higher-order.pdf)), but the resulting solution is not really written in a proper manner:

```
data Tree a = Leaf
            | Node Int (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            deriving (Show,Eq)


foldTree::[a]-> Tree a
foldTree a=_foldTree a 0 ((getHeight (length a))-1) (length a)
           where 
           _foldTree::[a]->Int->Int->Int->Tree a
           _foldTree a n h l
                        | n>=l = Leaf
                        | otherwise = Node h (_foldTree a (2*n+1) (h-1) l ) (a!!n) (_foldTree a (2*n+2) (h-1) l)


getHeight::Int->Int
getHeight n=ceiling(log (fromIntegral(n))/log 2)
```

The solution suffers from precision problems. And I think I can use some high level abstractions which I have been missing.

I am just making the heap (sort of, without ordering) out of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the output should be a balanced tree, it seems it's not required to be ordered in any way (at least the given example there isn't). So it's definitely not a heap. And the solution is required to use `foldr`, which yours doesn't satisfy.

You need to split the task into two parts:

1. Inserting a new element into a balanced tree so that the result is again a balanced tree. The signature of the function should look somewhat like

   ```
   insert :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
   ```

   If you're not sure how to implement `insert`, hover over the following box with another hint (but I'd strongly suggest you to try without it first):

   > Inserting into an empty tree is trivial. If the tree is nonempty, check both subtrees and recursively insert the element into the subtree with less height. (If the heights are the same, just pick whichever is more convenient.) Since inserting an element this way keeps the height of a tree or increases it just by 1, the resulting tree is also balanced.
2. Folding over the list using the insertion function. This part is easy, when you have 1.

Comment: My main problem is assigning and changing heights. How can I do so in single traversal. As you can see I am currently pre-calculating the heights and then assigning.

Comment: @user2179293 Don't think of the heights as something separate from nodes. The height is something that belongs to a node. I'd suggest you to implement two functions, AKA [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors), with signatures `leaf :: Tree a` (this will be just `Leaf`) and `node :: Tree a -> a  -> Tree a -> Tree a`. Having them, you can create and manipulate trees without caring about the heights at all - `node` will compute the correct height automatically behind the scenes.